Applying Block Bootstrap to Simulate Returns and Conduct OLS Regression for Beta Calculation
I am facing a methodological issue in my Master's thesis and hope someone can provide some guidance.
Background:
I have a time series of returns for the S&P 500, a variance swap, and a put option on the S&P 500. My goal is to simulate the true distribution of these returns and then perform an OLS regression to determine the market beta and the coefficient for the volatility risk premium based on the swap.
Approach:

Block Bootstrap:
I am using the block bootstrap method, where 10,000 start dates are randomly selected to split the time series into blocks and generate new simulated returns. This process results in 10,000 simulated observations for the returns of the S&P 500, the swap, and the option.

OLS Regression:
I then conduct a single OLS regression with the simulated returns to estimate the market beta of the option and the factor based on the swap.


Question:
Is it methodologically sound to perform the OLS regression in this manner on the simulated returns? Has anyone had experience with a similar methodology or knows of relevant literature that describes this approach? I am particularly looking for sources that discuss calculating beta through OLS regression on returns generated via block bootstrap.
Thank you in advance for your help!

I haven't heard of people using OLS on simulated returns, only historical realized returns.

Ahh sorry for the misunderstanding. The "simulated" returns are not actually a simulation but rather constructed based on historical realized returns. You take a random start date in the given data and look how well a certain asset performs over the next year. You do that for 10.000 times and have an estimate for an average return. As these are not "real" returns but closer to a back test or something I used "simulated" returns.
